# Passing variables from Model to Model in codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, variables

I need to pass a variable to model, that model needs to send another back and use that variable to query a different model.

EG:

I have a product_ID which I send to the product model, From that I find out the supplier_ID. I want to grab that supplier_ID to the supplier model to get the supplier name.

How do you implement this in codeigniter?

Answer (score 3):

I would generally do something like this in my controller:

```
$this->load->model('Products');
$this->load->model('Suppliers');

$result = $this->Suppliers->get_supplier_name($this->Products->get_product_supplier($product_id));
```

Comment: I need to get a value from the 'products' to send to 'suppliers', 

I tried using something like 
`$this->products_model->get_products($p_id, &$b_id);`

p_id is the product ID i send to get the correct information and b_id is what I want back

Answer (score 1):

I would do a join between the two tables and do one single query.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to set it as a public variable (see [visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) in OOP):

```
function blah() {
    public $product_id = 0;

    $this->load->model('Products');

    // Products model can set and access $this->product_id

    $this->load->model('Suppliers');

    // Suppliers model can also set and access $this->product_id
}
```

If you really wanted to in CI you could declare $product_id in your controller to make it truely global but I wouldn't do that personally for tidyness.

Answer (score 0):

Like kemp said, it sounds like a join would be your best bet:

```
// pass the $product_ID variable to the model
$this->db->select('supplier_tbl.supplier_name');
$this->db->from('supplier_tbl');
$this->db->join('product_tbl','product_tbl.supplier_ID = supplier_tbl.supplier_ID');
$this->db->where('product.tbl',$product_ID);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Of course, if you have a reason to keep the models separate, this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't something like this work for you?

```
$s_id = $this->product_model->getSupplierID($p_id);
$s_name = $this->supplier_model->getSupplierName($s_id);
```

Seems very straightforward to me. Or, perhaps you could clarify which this approach doesn't achieve what you need?